# How redirect home page in cake php

Tags: cakephp

In my cake php site, after login page redirect to result display page, but I need to redirect home page. Here is AppController.php code:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'results', 'action' => 'add'),

            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
        ),
        'Security'
    );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Just define loginRedirect

To force where a user is redirected to after login, just change the `loginRedirect`:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => '/', # <-
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
        ),
        'Security'
    );
}
```

Note that ordinarily [a user is redirected to whatever url they were attempting to access](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L699-L716) - with a default of `/`; as such it may be more appropriate to simply remove the `loginRedirect` key from the Auth component config.